# LaTeX2e \makebox !=\hbox?

Tags: boxes, latex-base

The `source2e` documentation (pg. 233) when describing `\makebox` states:

> ... If *wid*   is missing, then *pos* is also missing and *obj*  is put
>   in an `\hbox` of its natural width...

This, however, seems to be only half the story. It also puts a `\leavevmode` behind it, thus although the width is identical to that of a primitive `\hbox` the behaviour is not. In TeX two consecutive `\hboxes` will be typeset on two vertical lines, but in LaTeX2e they will stay on the same line. And `\leavevmode` is of course `\unhbox\voidb@x`.

Is a correction to the docs appropriate or am I wrong somewhere?

MWE for experimentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newbox\temp
\savebox\temp{test}
LaTeX

\makebox{test} \mbox{test}

TeX

\hbox{test} \hbox{test}

LaTeX with leavemode

\makeatletter
\leavevmode\hbox to \wd\temp{test} \unhbox\voidb@x\hbox to \wd\temp{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All the LaTeX box commands do `\leavevmode`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are of course correct. On the other hand the documentation isn't exactly wrong it just, as you say, doesn't tell the whole truth. This may not be the only line of the internal documentation about which that could be said, so it depends a bit how much resource anyone would want to allocate to changing such things.

That particular comment is only a lightly (semi-automatically) edited version of this

```
%  \makebox [WID][POS]{OBJ}
%          : puts OBJ in an \hbox of width WID, positioned by POS.
%            POS = l -> flushleft, POS = r -> flushright.
%            Default is centered.
%            If WID is missing, then POS is also missing and OBJ
%            is put in an \hbox of its natural width.
```

from the LaTeX 2.09 source, so it has been there a long time:-)

Comment: Thanks! I am not too sure if it is worth editing, personally I think, a lesson that the opensource community taught us is that small changes accumulate and in the long run docs and code improve tremendously. I also personally feel is worth a small edit of the docs.

Comment: True in general but as egreg noted the fact that is that all latex box commands use leavevmode, so that may be taken as given (although I just checked and ltbox.dtx doesn't actually say that anywhere explictly:-)

Comment: I am not surprised they do, as they use two macros essentially with the same essence, the rest is just parameter capturing.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides yes but what I meant is that latex never uses boxes in vertical mode, the use of `\leavevmode` is pervasive, and there is an argument that it need not be highlighted every time: not just `\makebox` but `\parbox`  in that file  `tabular` from lttab,  `\resizebox` and `\includegraphics` from graphics `\colorbox` from color etc all work the same way.

Comment: Agreed:) I will attribute my spending an hour debugging today to --as we get older we forget what the younger us read or wrote.